# Unexpected result given by Sum

Tags: list-manipulation, summation

Consider the following (minimal?) working example:

```
f[k_, lim_] := Module[{q, r},
   {q, r} = QuotientRemainder[lim - k (k + 1)/2 + 1, k]
];

Sum[f[k, 10^12], {k, 1000000}]

(* {14142725474025, 249498313774} *)

Sum[f[k, 10^12], {k, 1000001}]

(* Set::shape: Lists {q$28245507,r$28245507} and    
   QuotientRemainder[1000000000001-1/2 k (1+k),k] are not the same shape. *)

(* {14142725974023, 249498313776} *)

f[1000001, 10^12]

(* {499998, 2} *)

Total[Table[f[k, 10^12], {k, 1000001}]]

(* {14142725974023, 249498313776} *)
```

The function `f` returns a pair of integers through some arithmetic. If I sum up the first million, things work fine. If I sum up 1000001 of them, I get an error message. Even stranger, if I convert `Sum` to `Total[Table`, the error message goes away. Finally, simply evaluating `f` at the offending value (1000001) does not produce an error message.

Lastly, I just realized that I could simply remove the `{q,r}=` and the corresponding `Module`, leaving a one-line function for `f`. When I do this, the error vanishes.

Comment: This is `Sum[]` trying to be too clever by analyzing your summand, and failing. Try this: `Sum[f[k, 10^12], {k, 1000001}, Method -> "Procedural"]`.

Comment: Noticed defining f with `f[k_?NumericQ, lim_?NumericQ]` also does not produce error, so probably it's doing symbolic processing for some values?

Comment: This is explained in the `Possible Issues` section of the documentation for [`Sum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html)